# Replace in MySQL: Different values from a table to be replaced by "XXX"

Tags: mysql, replace

I want to replace lots of strings by "XXX". The strings to be replaced are in a special table. E. g. in the table there is "Mr. Smith", "Mr. Miller", ... (hundreds of records), and in one field in the other table there is e. g. "Dear Mr. Smith, thank you for ...". As a result it should be "Dear XXX, thank you for ...". How to do that?

The only idea I had was to create a loop in PHP and do it as a Cronjob. But is there any way to do it purely with a SQL statement?

Comment: e. g. "Dear somebody, or always Dear Somebody, ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have something similar to these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
                CustomerID SMALLSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,             
                Name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL);    

INSERT INTO Customer(Name) VALUES('Mr. Miller');
INSERT INTO Customer(Name) VALUES('Mr. Smith');     
INSERT INTO Customer(Name) VALUES('Mr. John');
INSERT INTO Customer(Name) VALUES('Mr. Alex');


Create table Template(
                TemplateID SMALLSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                Description VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO Template(Description) VALUES('Dear Mr. Smith, thank you for');
INSERT INTO Template(Description) VALUES('Dear Mr. John, thank you for');       
INSERT INTO Template(Description) VALUES('Dear Mr. Alex, thank you for');
```

You could use something like this.

```
SELECT customer.Name, template.description, REPLACE(template.description, customer.Name, 'XXX') 
FROM Customer INNER JOIN Template ON template.description LIKE CONCAT('%', Customer.name, '%');
```

And the result would be:

[image: And the result would be:]

The update Query would be something like:

```
WITH subquery AS (
    SELECT customer.Name, template.description, REPLACE(template.description, customer.Name, 'XXX') 
    FROM Customer INNER JOIN Template ON template.description LIKE CONCAT('%', Customer.name, '%')
)
UPDATE template
SET description = subquery.replace
FROM subquery;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the same table setup given in Claudio Corchez's answer here's how to do it without a subquery:

```
UPDATE `Template` AS t, 
    `Customer` AS c
SET t.`Description` = REPLACE(t.`Description`, c.`Name`, 'XXX')
WHERE t.`Description` LIKE CONCAT('%', c.`Name`, '%')
;
```

IMO this looks a little cleaner, but the answer with the subquery works just fine too.